# Determine the values of $x$ for which the given power series converges.

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

Determine the values of $x$ for which the power series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{n}}{n+1} \cdot (\frac{2x+1}{x})^{n } $ converges .

**Try:**

I've found the radius of convergence for the above power series is '$1$'. So we've to now solve the inequality $\frac{|2x+1|}{|x|} < 1$ to get the interval of convergence . After solving the inequality I've got the interval of convergence as $(-1,\frac{-1}{2}]$ .

**Question:**

I'm not sure about my answer . Please help!

**EDIT:**

The correct interval of convergence for the given power series is $(-1,\frac{-1}{3})$ .

Comment: Series does not converge for $x \ge -\frac{1}{3}$.  There is no radius of convergence.   It is not a power series in x.

Comment: @herbsteinberg  this will become power series of the form $\sum a_n y^n$ . if we assume $y=\frac{2x+1}{x}$ .

Comment: Power series in y has a radius of convergence of 1, leading to an interval  (-1,-1/3) for x convergence.

Comment: you are right ! thanks ! @herbsteinberg

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I've got the answer and don't want to bother anyone to answer.

Comment: Or you could just post the answer yourself now that you know what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x > 0$ implies $-x < 2x+1 < x$. This gives $x < -1$ and $x > \frac{-1}{3}$ which is not possible simultaneously.

For $x < 0$ we have $-x > 2x+1 > x$. This gives $-1 < x < \frac{-1}{3}$. So the required interval is $\left(-1,\frac{-1}{3}\right)$.

Comment: Okay ! Thanks !